# Classic ASP Calling .NET Component - how is threading handled?

Tags: .net, multithreading, iis, com, asp-classic

I'm calling a .NET component from Classic ASP that has been created using Server.CreateObject.

The question is, if multiple users are calling the page at the same time, will the calls to my object get queued or will it create another instance of the object for each request / thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request get's it's own thread.  So separate objects will be created.